# Maximum Likelihood with Gaussian distribution

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I am reading [this](http://zacklipton.com/media/papers/neural-heteroscedastic-regression.pdf) paper and came across an equation I don't really understand.
I learned the maximum likelihood method last semester.

However the functions that I saw always contained the parameter $\Theta$.
Then I took the log of the function, derived it and solved for $\Theta$.

I don't understand what parameter they are trying to find.
This is the equation (it is on page 5 of the paper):

[image]

Comment: The paper explains the notation a few paragraphs before the equation. $\hat y$ depends on parameters $W_l$ and $b_l$, which they denote collectively as $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the paper ${\hat y}_i$ and ${\hat \sigma}$ belong to a class of functions parameterized by $\theta$. So, $\theta$ is the vector of all parameters in ${\hat y}_i$ and ${\hat \sigma}$. For instance, if you consider a deep NN, $\theta$ contains all of the elements of $W_i$ and $b_i$ ($i \in \{1,2,\cdots,L\}$) in the expression above your equation.